# Regarding Text Autoencoders in KERAS for topic modeling

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, keras

**Introduction:** I have trained Autoencoders (vanilla & variational) in KERAS for MNIST images, and have observed how good the latent representation in the bottleneck layer looks for clustering them together.

**Objective:** I want to do the same for short texts. Tweets specifically! I want to cluster them together based on their semantics using [pre-trained GloVe embeddings](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/).

What I am planning to do is create a CNN encoder and a CNN decoder as a start, before moving on to LSTMs/GRUs.

**Problem:** 
~~~*What should be the correct loss? How do I implement it in Keras?*~~~

This is how my KERAS model looks like

INPUT_TWEET (Word indexes) >> EMBEDDING LAYER >> CNN_ENCODER >> BOTTLENECK >> CNN_DECODER >> OUTPUT_TWEET (Word indexes)

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Input_Layer (InputLayer)     (None, 64)                0         
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 64, 200)           3299400   
enc_DO_0_layer (Dropout)     (None, 64, 200)           0         
enc_C_1 (Conv1D)             (None, 64, 16)            9616      
enc_MP_1 (MaxPooling1D)      (None, 32, 16)            0         
enc_C_2 (Conv1D)             (None, 32, 8)             392       
enc_MP_2 (MaxPooling1D)      (None, 16, 8)             0         
enc_C_3 (Conv1D)             (None, 16, 8)             200       
enc_MP_3 (MaxPooling1D)      (None, 8, 8)              0         
***bottleneck (Flatten)***   (None, 64)                0         
reshape_2 (Reshape)          (None, 8, 8)              0         
dec_C_1 (Conv1D)             (None, 8, 8)              200       
dec_UpS_1 (UpSampling1D)     (None, 16, 8)             0         
dec_C_2 (Conv1D)             (None, 16, 8)             200       
dec_UpS_2 (UpSampling1D)     (None, 32, 8)             0         
dec_C_3 (Conv1D)             (None, 32, 16)            400       
dec_UpS_3 (UpSampling1D)     (None, 64, 16)            0         
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 64, 200)           9800      
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64, 1)             201       
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 64)                0         
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is clearly wrong because it tries to minimize the MSE loss between the Input and the Output (word indexes), where I think it should do it in the embedding layers (embedding_1 and conv1d_2).

Now how do I do it? Does it make sense? Is there a way to do this in Keras? Please check my code below:

**The code:**

```
sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32',name="Input_Layer")
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
embedded_sequences1 = Dropout(0.5, name="enc_DO_0_layer")(embedded_sequences)

x = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same',name="enc_C_1")(embedded_sequences1)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding='same',name='enc_MP_1')(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same',name="enc_C_2")(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding='same',name="enc_MP_2")(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same',name="enc_C_3")(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, padding='same',name="enc_MP_3")(x)

encoded = Flatten(name="bottleneck")(x)
x = Reshape((8, 8))(encoded)

x = Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same',name="dec_C_1")(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2,name="dec_UpS_1")(x)
x = Conv1D(8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same',name="dec_C_2")(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2,name="dec_UpS_2")(x)
x = Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu',padding='same',name="dec_C_3")(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2,name="dec_UpS_3")(x)
decoded = Conv1D(200, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
y = Dense(1)(decoded)
y = Flatten()(y)

autoencoder = Model(sequence_input, y)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

autoencoder.fit(x = tweet_word_indexes ,y = tweet_word_indexes,
            epochs=10,
            batch_size=128,
            validation_split=0.2)
```

**Dont want it to do this:**

It is obviously just trying to reconstruct the array of word indexes (zero padded) because of the bad loss.

```
Input  = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1641 13 2 309 932 1 10 5 6]  
Output = [ -0.31552997 -0.53272009 -0.60824025 -1.14802313 -1.14597917 -1.08642125 -1.10040164 -1.19442761 -1.19560885 -1.19008029 -1.19456315 -1.2288748 -1.22721946 -1.20107424 -1.20624077 -1.24017036 -1.24014354 -1.2400831 -1.24004364 -1.23963416 -1.23968709 -1.24039733 -1.24027216 -1.23946059 -1.23946059 -1.23946059 -1.23946059 -1.23946059 -1.23946059 -1.23946059 -1.23946059 -1.23946059 -1.23946059 -1.14516866 -1.20557368 -1.5288837 -1.48179781 -1.05906188 -1.17691648 -1.94568193 -1.85741842 -1.30418646 -0.83358657 -1.61638248 -1.17812908 0.53077424 0.79578459 -0.40937367 0.35088596 1.29912627 -5.49394751 -27.1003418 -1.06875408 33.78763962 109.41391754 242.43798828 251.05577087 300.13430786 267.90420532 178.17596436 132.06596375 60.63394928 82.10819244 91.18526459]
```

**Question:**
*Does it make sense to you? What should be the correct loss? How do I implement it in Keras?*

Comment: What are your outputs? I'm not quite following when you say `Word indexes`. The dictionary of words on twitter is upward of 2M. Can you expand on your expected output representation some?

Comment: Being it an autoencoder, the outputs are the same as the inputs. But maybe choosing the "format" of this output is one of the keypoints of the question.

Comment: @DavidParks Sorry for the confusion. For example a tweet is "All work and no play makes jack a dull boy", then word_indexes would be like [44, 88, 43, 1, 475, 101, 11 , 26 ,465, 111]

Comment: I understand what a tweet is, how are you representing the sentence "All work and no play makes jack a dull boy" in numeric form? That's the part that isn't clear to me. Your input is a sequence of embedded vectors, are you proposing the same form for your output?

Comment: @DanielMöller Yes. Just like in images, your aim is to minimize pixel-by-pixel error. Here I do not want to minimize the word-by-word error, but in the Embedding space. For instance, "IDIOT" and "STUPID" are totally different words when you just look at the text, but very close to each other in the Embedding space.

Comment: Outputing embeddings should not work, or if you find a way to do that you should be published in Nature for it. Embeddings do not produce a smooth space over which you can apply a differentiable loss function such as square error.

Comment: The closest thing I've seen used is in google translate where they output "word parts" or what I think of as syllabols (though that isn't quite accurate). I believe they use a vector of 16k word-parts across 50+ languages that they reconstruct back into words.

Comment: Are you sure (honest question, no sarcasm)? I mean, embeddings are trainable.

Comment: @DavidParks: These are the word indexes from the dictionary. A kind of Word to Integer mapping. To your second question - I want to reconstruct not the actual tweet (the words) but what you get in the embedding space. For instance, if you have 10 words and the embedding space will give you a matrix of 10 by 200 size. I can treat it as an image & then train the autoencoder on it to reconstruct it, but this is just super expensive to do. I want to use the Embedding Layer as KERAS gives you, & modify the loss so that it doesnt use FIRST and the LAST layers, but SECOND and the SECOND LAST layers.

Comment: I would love a reference to something that produces embeddings at the output. For the input they are great, but if you think about the space they create it's not smooth, e.g. not differentiable, e.g. not useful as an output. I've long wished to do this myself.

Comment: The auto encoder will give you the embedding for sure, a linearly seperable space where some meaning, useful in reconstruction, has been established. But that's not a differentiable space. Think about word2vec and how you move from one word to another. You can't reasonably move smoothly through that space to transition from a wrong answer to a right answer. You don't get incrementally better, you "jump" from one meaning to another. Herein lies the crux of the problem with embeddings on the output.

Comment: Doesn't this "jump" also occur with classes that have absolutely no relation to each other? At the end you use a distance criteria to transform the continuous output into a discrete classification. The embedding would do the same, but with a more complex criteira.

Comment: In classification each class is effectively independent, it's either more or less of each class. In the embedding space you have some meaning such as "royalty" (as in the famous king-queen-man-woman word2vec example). As you change the degree of royalty in the embedding the other vectors, and overall meaning, are highly dependent on this change. In the classification they did not have this dependency. In any case, awesome question and discussion!

Comment: @DanielMöller You are right, a closely related question  was asked here,    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735205/keras-autoencoder-for-text-analysis     but the only solution posted there, separates the Embedding_Layer from the real model, and that is why you cant Train good word embeddings - Embedding(trainable=True)

Comment: You might consider a triplet loss if you can massage your problem into a form where you have two points that should be considered the same and one point that should be considered different, this is used in face recognition: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not try to get indices at the end of the model (indices are not differentiable and don't follow a logical continuous path).

You should probably finish the model with one-hot encoded words. Then you use "softmax" with "categorical_crossentropy". (Not sure if it's the best solution, though)

The final layer should be `Dense(dicWordCount)`.
So you convert your indices to one-hot vectors and pass them as the output.

```
oneHotOutput = np.zeros((tweetCount,length,dicWordCount))
auxIndices = np.arange(length)

#inputIndices has shape (tweets,length), it's your array of indices
for i, tweet in zip(range(tweetCount),inputIndices):
    oneHotOutput[i][auxIndices,tweet] = 1
```

Create the model and: `model.fit(inputIndices,oneHotOutput,...)`