# Keras autoencoder and getting the compressed feature vector representation

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I have one sentence per row in a file and sentences are not more than 30 words. I am building an autoencoder using Keras and I am very new to this - so I may be doing few things incorrectly. So, help me out here.

I am trying to use autoencoder to get the intermediate context vector - the compressed feature vectors after the encode step.
Vocabulary is nothing but a list of distinct words in my file. 300 is the dimension of word embedding matrix. 30 is the maximum words each sentence can have. X_train is (#of sentence, 30) matrix of numbers where each number is nothing but where in the dictionary the word existed.

```python
print len(vocabulary)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(vocabulary), 300))
model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')

input_i = Input(shape=(30, 300))
encoded_h1 = Dense(64, activation='tanh')(input_i)
encoded_h2 = Dense(32, activation='tanh')(encoded_h1)
encoded_h3 = Dense(16, activation='tanh')(encoded_h2)
encoded_h4 = Dense(8, activation='tanh')(encoded_h3)
encoded_h5 = Dense(4, activation='tanh')(encoded_h4)
latent = Dense(2, activation='tanh')(encoded_h5)
decoder_h1 = Dense(4, activation='tanh')(latent)
decoder_h2 = Dense(8, activation='tanh')(decoder_h1)
decoder_h3 = Dense(16, activation='tanh')(decoder_h2)
decoder_h4 = Dense(32, activation='tanh')(decoder_h3)
decoder_h5 = Dense(64, activation='tanh')(decoder_h4)

output = Dense(300, activation='tanh')(decoder_h5)

autoencoder = Model(input_i,output)

autoencoder.compile('adadelta','mse')

X_embedded = model.predict(X_train)
autoencoder.fit(X_embedded,X_embedded,epochs=10, batch_size=256, validation_split=.1)

print autoencoder.summary()
```

The idea is taken from [Keras - Autoencoder for Text Analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735205/keras-autoencoder-for-text-analysis)

So, after training (if I have done correctly) how should I just run the encoding part for each sentence to get the feature representation? Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer

Answer (score 1):

make a standalone model for encoder

```
encoder=Model(input_i,latent)
```

suppose for mnist data the code should be like--

```
encoder.predict(x_train[0])
```

by this you will get latent_space vector as output

Answer (score 0):

To do this, refer to 'popping' off last layer via `model.pop()`. After training "pop off" the last layer by using `model.pop()`, then use `model.predict(X_train)` to get the representation.

https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-remove-a-layer-from-a-sequential-model